# Converting AES Decryption from C# to JavaScript in Node.js with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption

How do I convert the following C# code to JavaScript using the CryptoJS AES Node.js library node-crypto-aes?

```
{
    private string encrypted = "IgOAfoyFZuo5qJ2if19nmCWEH4FfYHXL7Xx0Jq/t+DQ=";
    private string vector = "gRXkAxKFHbWjAwTlRZeUGw==";
    private string secretKey = "3fe68bec63b9ab1eac71afee33728854";

    private string result;
    byte[] IV = Convert.FromBase64String(vector);
    byte[] Key = Convert.FromBase64String(secretKey);
    byte[] textBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
    SymmetricAlgorithm sa = RijndaelManaged.Create();

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(textBytes);
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, sa.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[textBytes.Length];

    int decryptedByteCount = cs.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);

    ms.Close();
    cs.Close();

    result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

I have attempted this, but the result is an emtpy "words" array, with a sigBytes value of 0. The expected result string should be a fixed-length string like an ID with leading zeros (like an ID, i.e. "0000000000005555").

```
var CryptoJS = require('node-cryptojs-aes').CryptoJS;

var iv = new Buffer('gRXkAxKFHbWjAwTlRZeUGw==', 'base64');
var key = new Buffer('3fe68bec63b9ab1eac71afee33728854', 'base64');
var encrypted = new Buffer('IgOAfoyFZuo5qJ2if19nmCWEH4FfYHXL7Xx0Jq/t+DQ=', 'base64');

var data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv });
console.log(data);
```

Result:

```
{ words: [], sigBytes: 0 }
```

**Attempt to use CryptoJS to convert from Base64**

```
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('gRXkAxKFHbWjAwTlRZeUGw==');
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('3fe68bec63b9ab1eac71afee33728854');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('IgOAfoyFZuo5qJ2if19nmCWEH4FfYHXL7Xx0Jq/t+DQ=');

var data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { iv: iv });
console.log(data);
```

Result:

```
{ words: [], sigBytes: 0 }
```

Comment: The key looks more like a hexadecimal number than base64 encoded.

Comment: @Kevin It sure looks like that, but both snippets treat the key exactly the same. And the strange thing is that this is a valid Base64 encoding which when decoded produced an AES of a valid length.

Comment: @Bibble CryptoJS doesn't work with `Buffer`s, but rather with its own binary format which is `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray`. Try to change `new Buffer(<...>, 'base64')` to `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(<...>)`.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I changed that, but the value of `data` is still `{ words: [], sigBytes: 0 }`